Use interface projection to map child data to child dto and place them inside the main interface DTO
This is the entity class of a table named JobCard.
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@SQLRestriction("is_active = true")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE job_card SET is_active = false WHERE Id = ?")
@Table(name = "job_card")
public class JobCard extends BaseEntity {

    private String generatedId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "jobCard", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<JobParts> spareParts;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "jobCard", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<JobService> jobCardServices;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "assigned_with")
    private Technician assignedWith;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "workshop_id")
    private Workshop workshop;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "handover_id")
    private Driver handoverMTO;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "takeover_id")
    private Driver takeoverMTO;


    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> complains;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "prepared_by_id")
    private Employee preparedBy;

    private LocalDateTime issuingDate;
    private LocalDateTime handoverDate;
    private Short status;
}

It extends a class named BaseEntity; I have prepared this class to include all of the common table attributes. All entity classes in my application extend this class. Here are the contents of the BaseEntity class.
@MappedSuperclass
@Setter
@Getter
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdTime;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CreatedBy
    private User createdBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LastModifiedBy
    private User updatedBy;

    private Boolean isActive = true;

    @PrePersist
    private void onBasePersist() {
        User user = Helper.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null && this.createdBy == null) {
            this.createdBy = user;
        }
        this.isActive = true;
    }


    @PreUpdate
    private void onBaseUpdate() {
        User user = Helper.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            this.updatedBy = user;
        } else {
            this.updatedBy = this.createdBy;
        }
    }

}

You can see that it has attributes like id, created time, updated time, created by, and updated by; these attributes are common in all entities.
Now, the JobCard entity has many-to-one relationships with the following entities: Vehicle, Technician, Workshop, Driver, and Employee. I am not bothered with these entities; I am bothered with those entities that have many-to-one relationships with JobCard; namely JobParts and JobService.
These are the contents of JobParts.
public class JobParts extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parts_id")
    private Parts parts;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "unit_id")
    private Unit partsUnit;

    private Integer quantity;

    private Long cost;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_card_id")
    private JobCard jobCard;
}

And, these are the contents of the entity class JobService.
public class JobService extends BaseEntity {
    private String title;
    private Double cost;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_card_id")
    private JobCard jobCard;
}

Now, I want to use an interface projection to fetch only the selected values of JobCard. While fetching that projection, additionally I want to fetch some columns of JobParts and JobService too.
This is the main projection interface I've prepared for Job Card.
public interface JobCardProjection {
    Long getId();

    Long getVehicleId();

    String getLicense();

    String getEngine();

    String getChassisNo();

    String getModel();

    String getYearModel();

    Long getPartsCost();

    Set<JobPartsProjection> getSpareParts();

    Set<JobServiceProjection> getServices();

    Double getServiceCost();

    Set<String> getComplains();

    Long getPreparedById();

    String getPreparedByName();

    Long getAssignedWithId();

    String getAssignedWithName();

    Long getHandoverId();

    String getHandoverName();

    Long getTakeoverId();

    String getTakeoverName();

    String getStatus();

    LocalDateTime getIssueDate();

    LocalDateTime getHandoverDate();
}

Inside this projection interface, there are two more projection interfaces, for Job Parts and Job Service respectively.
Here are their contents.
This one is for Job Parts.
public interface JobPartsProjection {
    Long getJobCardPartsId();

    String getGeneratedId();

    Long getPartsId();

    String getPartsName();

    Long getUnitId();

    String getUnitName();

    Integer getPartsQuantity();

    Long getCost();
}

And, this one is for JobService.
public interface JobServiceProjection {
    Long getServiceId();

    String getServiceTitle();

    Double getCost();
}

Now, I'm struggling to write a query that will fetch the requested column values of Job Card as well as of Job Parts and Job Service.
I've written this query for the repository method; however, it is failing to do what I intend.
@Query(value = """
                SELECT jobcard.id as id,
                       vehicle.id as vehicleId,
                       vehicle.licenseNo as license,
                       vehicle.engineNo as engine,
                       vehicle.chassisNo as chassisNo,
                       vehicle.model as model,
                       vehicle.yearModel as yearModel,
                       SUM(parts.cost) as partsCost,
                       parts.id as jobCardPartsId,
                       jobcard.generatedId as generatedId,
                       parts.parts.id as partsId,
                       parts.parts.name as partsName,
                       parts.partsUnit.id as unitId,
                       parts.partsUnit.fullName as unitName,
                       parts.quantity as partsQuantity,
                       parts.cost as cost,
                       services.id as serviceId,
                       services.title as serviceTitle,
                       services.cost as serviceCost,
                       SUM(services.cost) as totalServiceCost,
                       jobcard.complains as complains,
                       preparedBy.id as preparedById,
                       preparedBy.name as preparedByName,
                       assignedWith.id as assignedWithId,
                       assignedWith.name as assignedWithName,
                       handoverMTO.id as handoverId,
                       handoverMTO.name as handoverName,
                       takeoverMTO.id as takeoverId,
                       takeoverMTO.name as takeoverName,
                       jobcard.status as status,
                       jobcard.issuingDate as issueDate,
                       jobcard.handoverDate as handoverDate
                FROM JobCard jobcard
                LEFT JOIN jobcard.spareParts parts
                LEFT JOIN jobcard.jobCardServices services
                JOIN jobcard.vehicle vehicle
                JOIN jobcard.assignedWith assignedWith
                JOIN jobcard.workshop workshop
                JOIN jobcard.handoverMTO handoverMTO
                JOIN jobcard.takeoverMTO takeoverMTO
                JOIN jobcard.preparedBy preparedBy
                WHERE jobcard.id = :id
                GROUP BY jobcard.id
            """)
    Optional<JobCardProjection> findJobCardById(@PathVariable Long id);

This method is throwing an error; the error states that it fails to fetch unique rows. I can assume why. Due to the one-to-many relationship between job parts and job service; while fetching a row of job card, multiple rows of job parts and job services are fetched. That's why the mapping to the interface fails.
Is there any way to fetch the child rows and map them to the concerned interfaces? As a temporary solution, I have used join fetch to fetch data from all related entities of Job card and then mapped the result to a response class. On the
contrary, that's not an efficient workaround.
Any help and advice on this will be appreciated.
